# How accurate are blood count tests?

Tags: blood-tests

I just started to read about blood count, I am wondering how accuratelly can be determimed the number of red blood cells in case of [Rouleaux formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouleaux) or [agglutination of red cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_cell_agglutination)?

Comment: With red cell agglutination "red blood cell count may be falsely decreased, and the MCV falsely increased, as clumps of red cells are measured as single cells" https://imagebank.hematology.org/image/60305/red-cell-agglutination?type=atlas